# Can we say that a pointer value designates an object?

Tags: c, object

For example,

```
int a = 10;
```

Obviously, `a` designates `int` object which stores `10`. But is it true to say that `&a` designates an object? Since `&a` is an address value, I think it designates one byte object in memory!

Comment: I don't actually know what you intend "designates" to mean, but to me `&a` is a pointer that points to some "object".

Comment: `a` *is* an `int` *variable* which *contains* `10`. There is no 'designates' or 'object' about it. Therefore there is no 'designates object' about the address of `a` either. Whatever `a` is, `&a` is a pointer to it.

Comment: @EJP Are you saying that the terms 'designate' and 'object' are not standard terms in C?

Comment: I am saying exactly what I said, no more and no less. I'm not at all fond of this 'so are you saying game'.

Comment: @EJP if someone says "so are you saying" it means they don't know what you are trying to say, i.e your comment was unclear to them. In this case your comment has multiple factual errors which is why OP was confused

Comment: Using the terminology found in §6.2.1/4 of the C11 draft specification, `a` is an identifier that designates an entity of type `int`. However, `&a` doesn't designate anything, it's just a value that can be stored in a pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the C Standard's terminology, lvalue expressions can designate a memory location. `&a` is not an lvalue so it does not designate anything.

Comment: Can you explain why a pointer value is not a lvalue? According to ISO C11 6.3.2.1, it says that lvalue is an expression that potentially designates an object. And since a pointer value designates a one byte object I think a pointer value should be a lvalue!

Comment: Can you explain what lvalues have to do with the question?

Comment: @Jin the pointer value does not designate an object . Also there are no one-byte objects anywhre in this code, the `int` is likely to be 2 or 4 bytes.

Comment: @EJP Lvalues can designate a storage location. Other expressions can't.

Comment: lol @ the random delete vote

Comment: @M.M Doesn't each byte in memory have memory address? This is why I thought pointer value(memory address) may designate a one byte object in memory.

Comment: @Jin each byte has an address, but `&a` is the address of a whole int, not just one byte of it.  You seem to be mixing up "designate" with "points to".

Comment: @M.M Oh then instead of printing out all the 2 or 4 address values, `&a` just prints one address value, which is the first address of `a`?

Comment: @Jin in C an address always includes a type; if you "print out" an address in numeric form then you are only printing one aspect of the address (which might look the same as the address of a byte at the same location)

Comment: @M.M By the way, is it just a rule or is there a reason for why pointer value can't be lvalue?

Comment: @Jin they just aren't, lvalues designate a memory location. there is no memory location associated with `&a`

Comment: @M.M I'm still confused about "designate" and "points to"! Can you help me clarify these two terms? My guess is that "designating" means refering to 'contents' of memory

Comment: @Jin there's not anything more to say really. `a` designates an int and doesn't point to it. `&a` points to it and doesn't designate.