# What does 'designate an object' mean in C?

Tags: c, object

For example,

```
int x = 10;
```

we say that "`x` designates an int object which stores 10". But what does "designate" exactly mean? Does it mean `x` behaves like a label which refers to the whole chunk of memory?

Comment: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/designate

Comment: uh didn't you just ask this a couple of hours ago

Comment: If there is no meaning given in the standard, the normal english meaning applies: There's an `int`-object, and `x` is it's name.

Comment: @M.M Not quite: [Can we say that a pointer value designates an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030590/can-we-say-that-a-pointer-value-designates-an-object)

Comment: @Deduplicator I think they are essentially the same, if you understand the answer to one then you understand the other

Comment: I've closed the other question as a dupe pointing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `x` is an *identifier*.
2. There is an `int` object (i.e. a region of storage) containing the value `10`.
3. The identifier `x` is associated with that `int` object.

The C standard uses the English word [designate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/designate) to express the relationship between an identifier and the object it identifies.  You could say the same thing in several different ways. I said "associate" just now, there are many words we could choose. "`x` is a label for this region of memory" would be another way.

Note: designating is not limited to identifiers. Other expressions can designate an object too. For example `*(&x)` also designates the same object, as does `*(&x + 0)`.

When an expression designates an object, the expression may be used to either assign a value to the object, or retrieve the value from the object. (The same syntax covers both of those cases; it depends on context whether the value is read or written).

The word *lvalue* means an expression that might designate an object (according to the above definition of 'designate').

Comment: Does object refer to the chunk of memory or does it refer to value (such as int,float,string literal,pointer values...) stored in the memory?

Comment: @Jin "object" refers to the chunk of memory. The thing stored in the memory is called the "value".